# How can I store head node of a linked list in a function during recursion

Tags: recursion, linked-list

I have written a function to output a linked list in reverse order. Is there a way I can store the head node?

```
void output_rev_backtracking(Node *x) {
    Node *t=x;
    if(x==NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        output_rev_backtracking(x->next);
        if(x==t) {
            cout << x->data << "\n";
        } else {
            cout << x->data << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

This code is wrong since "x" changes to "x->next" in every step. How should I store "x" in "t"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void recursive_reverse(Node* current, Node* new_head){
if(!current)
    return;

Node* next = current->next;  
if(!new_head){
    new_head = current;
    new_head->next = null;
}else{
    current->next = new_head;
    new_head = current;
}

recursive_reverse(next, new_head);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).